# To do a sortable column of different links in wicket

Tags: java, wicket-6

I would like to create a table, with a column of links, each link will open a page of the respective object it represents.
For example, the column will display the number of an invoice, which is a link. When we click on one of these links a page is opened displaying the details for that invoice.
I'm trying to do it like this:
I've created a class `GuidLinkPanel.java`, where I'm putting the `ajaxLink`

```
import org.apache.wicket.AttributeModifier;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;

import nl.riskco.liberobc.client.business.model.InvoiceDomain;
import nl.riskco.liberobc.web.pages.details.DetailsPage;

public class GuidLinkPanel extends Panel {

    public GuidLinkPanel(final String id, IModel<InvoiceDomain> invoice)
    {
        super(id);

        add(new AjaxLink<Void>("guid"){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
            params.add("invoiceId", invoice.getObject().getInvoiceGUID());
            setResponsePage(DetailsPage.class, params);
            }
        }); 
    }       
}
```

Its markup

```
<wicket:panel>
    <wicket:message key="invoice-header">[invoice-header]</wicket:message>
    <a href="#" wicket:id="guid"></a>
</wicket:panel>
```

Now an excerpt of the class where the table is created, I also would like this column to be sortable, so I'm doing this:

```
columns.add(new PropertyColumn<InvoiceDomain, String>(new 
StringResourceModel("invoice-id-label", this, null), "invoiceGUID", 
"invoiceGUID"));

columns.add(new AbstractColumn<InvoiceDomain,String>(new Model<>("Invoice ID"),"invoiceGUID"){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<InvoiceDomain>> item, String componentId, IModel<InvoiceDomain> rowmodel)
            {
                item.add(new GuidLinkPanel(componentId, rowmodel));
            }
        });
```

The markup

```
<wicket:panel>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table">
         <table wicket:id="invoices-table" class="table table-striped"
</table>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</wicket:panel>
```

**The result:**

The column is added, but in each line the string

**[GuidLinkPanel[Component id=cell]]]**

and it is not a link.
Does anyone has a suggestion how to do this?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example

Comment: My issue is not make them sortable, my issue is that I want to see the invoice guid displayed in the table and as a link, but instead I get [GuidLinkPanel[Component id=cell]]] .

Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your AjaxLink doesn't have a text sub-element, e.g. `<a ...>Some Text to click</a>`.

You can do either:

- ajaxLink.setBody(Model.of(invoice.getObject().getInvoiceGUID()))
- or ajaxLink.add(new Label("linkLabel", invoice.getObject().getInvoiceGUID()). But here you will have to add an HTML element too: `<a wicket:id="guid><wicket:container wicket:id="linkLabel"/></a>`